Подключение скриптов и стилей на уровень выше корневой директории
Пытаюсь реализовать собственную cms для своего сайта в качестве практики php, но столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Имеется иерархия проекта описанная выше.
В папке core основные важные скрипты, по типу базового контроллера, подключения к БД и др,
В папке develop находятся пользовательские контроллеры, представления, модели и шаблоны
В папке public только .htaccess, index.php который вызывает bootstrap.php из core и иконка сайта
При нужном url я вызываю требуемый контроллер и подключаю:

шапку сайта
представление
подвал сайта

но мне очень нравится идея с шаблонами, и понравилась bitrix структура шаблонов, поэтому я хотел бы сделать это и у себя. Шаблоны, как я и писал выше, хранятся в /develop/templates.
Корневая директория сайта /public/
Пробовал относительные пути по совету ChatGPT и людей с форумов, не помогает
(../../develop/...)

Пробовал реализовать перенаправление в htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/templates/admin/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/develop/templates/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/../templates/$1 [L,R=301]

но пока что ничего не помогает, а хранить шаблоны в public мне не очень нравится...
Собственно, вопрос:
Можно ли реализовать подключение стилей, скриптов, картинок через php и htaccess, не затрагивая конфиг файл httpd?
Пока что видел только такое решение, но хотел бы его избежать, чтобы сайт был легк переносим.
P.S. Забыл написать, что также нашел решение
echo '<style>';
include <путь к стилю>
echo '</style>';

Насколько такое решение будет... Неправильным, при создании шаблонов?
И насколько будет неправильно вынести develop и core директории в public и почему?

Непонятно, при чем здесь папки core и develop. Вынести их можно, но непонятно зачем. Выносить надо только то, что должен видеть браузер - ассеты.

Разумеется, никакой веб-сервер никогда и ничего не отдаст клиенту, из расположенного выше корневой директории. Иначе это будет не веб-сервер, а решето. И если "люди с форумов" и ChatGPT пытаются предложить решение, это говорит только об их профнепригодности.
Все требуемые браузеру ресурсы - те самые assets (стили, картинки, скрипты, фонты и так далее) - должны лежать в пределах корневой директории сайта.
В качестве паллиативного решения можно в корне веб-сайта делать символическую ссылку на папку assets. Ну или не мудрствовать лукаво, а просто размещать ассеты сразу в корне.
А вот шаблоны, которые парсит РНР, вполне могут лежать выше корня сайта. И в шаблонах ссылки на эти ресурсы всегда должны быть абсолютными от корня сайта. То есть если в папке public есть папка /assets/admin, то путь к скрипту будет /assets/admin/js/script.js. Если в корне есть просто папка /js/, то путь писать как /js/script.js
Через РНР подключить можно всё. Всегда можно сделать ссылку на РНР скрипт, который прочитает нужный файл из папки выше корня, выдаст подходящий НТТР заголовок и отдаст содержимое клиенту. Но это как чесать левой ногой правое ухо. Не говоря уже о том, что этот скрипт должен будет отдавать только строго определенные файлы, а не воообще всё что угодно, что для новичка будет представлять проблему.
Запихивать содержимое стилевых файлов и скриптов прямо в HTML код можно, но считается дурным тоном. И лучше сразу учиться работать ассетами нормально.

Большое спасибо!
Вы и научили меня не делать "решето", и новому слову "паллиативный")
Но единственный вопрос, который остался...
Я читал про директорию public, core
public - в нее могут получить доступ извне
Зачем отделять ради безопасности скрипты и публичную часть на сайтах с перенаправлением?
Ведь, если работает перенаправление, то, по сути, я могу сам указать, что можно показать, а что нет, разве не так?

Ну это все больше суеверия и привычки. И немного логики. Во-первых, ни о какой "безопасности" тут речь не идет. Безопасность может касаться только конфигурационных файлов, если они не в формате .php. Для всех остальных файлов нет никакой разницы, доступны они из браузера, или нет. А во-вторых, а зачем "указывать, что можно показать, а что нет"? Зачем этим вообще себе специально  забивать голову, если можно просто поместить выше корня? Отсюда простая привычка и здравый смысл - в корне только то, что нужно браузеру.
